# chern character of wedge product of bundles

Tags: vector-bundles

It is well known that the, for Chern character of vector bundles, 
$$ ch (E \otimes F)= ch(E) \wedge ch(F)$$
holds true.
What about $E \wedge E$ when $E$ is holomorphic vector bundle?

Comment: What does $E\wedge F$ mean for vector bundles (or just vector spaces)?

Comment: right, it was just my fantasy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to get it via the splitting principle. Supposing $E=L_1\oplus L_2\oplus\dots\oplus L_n$, where $L_k$'s are line bundles, $ch(L_k)=e^{x_k}$ ($x_k$ the 1st Chern class of $L_k$) we get $ch(E\wedge E)=\sum_{i<j}e^{x_i+x_j}=\bigl((\sum_{k}e^{x_k})^2-\sum_{k}e^{2x_k}\bigr)/2$, hence
$$ch(E\wedge E)=\bigl((ch(E))^2-r_2\cdot ch(E)\bigr)/2$$
where $r_2$ acts on $H^{2k}$ by multiplying by $2^k$.

Comment: Are you sure it is always possible to write a holomorphic vector bundle $E$ as sum of line bundles?

Comment: OK, I think this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_principle answers my question

Comment: Could I ask what happens here if $ch(E)$ has odd rank, i.e. odd $ch_0(E)$? Because then $ch_0(E \wedge E) \in \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z}$, and I thought $ch_0$ should always be integral?

Comment: @mathphys thanks, there was a mistake (now corrected)

Comment: @user8268 Thanks!