# Formula for $\mathrm{ch}(E \wedge E)$ gives fractional rank of $E \wedge E$?

Tags: complex-geometry, vector-bundles

$\newcommand{\ch}{\mathrm{ch}}$In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/511973/252641), we have the following formula for the Chern character of a wedge of the vector bundle $E$ on $X$:

$$ \ch(E \wedge E) = \frac{1}{2} \ch(E)^2  - r_2 \cdot \ch(E)$$
where $r_2$ acts on $H^{2k}(X, \mathbb{Q})$ by multiplication by $2^k$.

My question is as follows: say $E$ has odd rank i.e. $\mathrm{rk}(E) = \ch_0(E)$ is odd. Then $\ch_0(E \wedge E) \in \frac{1}{2} \mathbb{Z}$, but I thought $\ch_0$, i.e. the rank, should always be integral. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: I think there is an error in linked post. The second term should be multiplied by 1/2.

Comment: Hmm, I agree - let's say for example that the rank of $E$ is 3. Going by the fact that e.g. $\mathrm{rk}(\wedge^2 E) = 3$, the second term should indeed have a $1/2$ in front. It seems as though the action by $r_2$ is OK too, with this adjustment.